# Pull requests as knowledge transfer: an anti-pattern?

Tags: pull-requests

I assumed that the purpose of pull requests within a team is to get a second set of eyes and basically proofread the code. But lately I am noticing that they can serve an additional function of preventing knowledge silos. The logic is that if every piece of code you write goes through a PR, then we preclude the danger of code which is unfamiliar to anyone except the author, increase the bus factor, and generally drive developers staying in the loop about projects they are not personally developing. If PRs are strategically spread out instead of always assigning to the same person, then these benefits become pretty strong.

By this logic, I am tempted to consider the "proofreading" to be a very secondary benefit of PRs. Correctness is checked in any case by automated and manual tests, careful design, and double checking my own work (though the fresh look from someone else doesn't hurt). The primary purpose of the PR is "FYI" - it is like an announcement to other developers of possibly significant changes I am implementing (if they are definitely significant, I would make an actual announcement eg. during a meeting).

This has impact on how the PRs are made. With the "proofread" logic, the main question is too big and hard to review PR vs. too trivial PR (simple changes that are obviously correct). But with the "FYI" logic, the question is whether the PR encapsulates a change that someone else should know about. Therefore extremely trivial PRs are still a good idea because even though there is no real need to proofread, the change is still worth communicating.

Is my thinking logical, or is this understanding of PRs an antipattern that causes problems down the line?

Comment: Are you referencing to specific git workflows?

Comment: Why not explicitely request _code reviews_ instead of using PRs to suggest that a code review is needed?

Answer (score 3):

To me, PRs are not a suitable vehicle for teaching *domain knowledge*. PRs are too random to do that (there is a poor signal to noise level when it comes to interesting information nuggets), the discoverability is low (who wants to dig around old PRs for information? are they searchable?) and there is a mismatch of the audience (everyone who needs to know) and what's practical in a PR.

Having said that, it's not wrong, it's a desirable side effect. I think they are useful to teach implementation strategies and best practices to the original author. But it doesn't completely solve the problem.

If I need people to know how the code works, I do an in-person code walk-through. We also do cross-team sprint demos.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your logic is flawed.

1. Simply reading a PR by itself is unlikely to impart understanding of the code base.
2. If only a single person reads and approves each PR and you spread the approvers widely, then each team member will only see a small scattered sample of changes.
3. Approving PRs is a pain. People will skip checking the code if they are assigned random PRs and just hit approve.

If we follow your reasoning to its conclusion you would have the least experienced team members approving PRs in order to 'train them up' and the most experienced members not doing any, which seems like a reversal of the standard "second pair of eyes" idea.

PRs are possibly of doubtful use in a commercial setting, but we can all understand the idea of Requesting the *owners* of the code base review our suggested changes and, if they find the changes acceptable, incorporate them into *their* code base.

The owners have an interest in maintaining whatever standards they think are required and are necessarily experts in the subject matter, able to judge the PR.

When they have the job of doing the PRs the system works. If you replace them with newbies then they wont have those interests, I don't think they will be motivated to read the PR they will just click accept.

Comment: i. Doing a PR requires some knowledge of the code base... so the act of PRing is to force someone to obtain this knowledge and demonstrate it. ii. this is accurate, but I guess I few a scattered sample of changes as quite valuable for understanding the project  iii.  Is true unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing communication through a channel that was not designed with that activity in mind is always an anti-pattern.

Now if the code/documents/etc that you are changing are at the right level of detail, then yes they can be used as a vehicle for communicating domain knowledge. However:

- they would need to be viewed by the team (or a large portion there of) which is a lot of overhead, in order to serve that purpose.
- generally speaking those people do not care about this section of the code, as they are working on other things. Doubtlessly they would have to consult the code again later should they become interested.
- and there are more effective ways to communicate with the team: Design Documents, Stories, Presentations, the water cooler...

Comment: "forcing communication" of course trying to communicate information about the code  base when there is no reason to do so out of a vague notion of onboarding might be viewed as forcing communication. A single virtue of PRs is that they are *real* and relate to actual work.

Comment: @AttRigh That is indeed an advantage, and once the PR is closed, how do they find that knowledge? Ask the person who remembers it was PR-2376? Remember the work happened somewhere in the second quarter of last year and trawl through the hundreds (or more) of commits? Maybe they were smart enough to link to an external document system? Wait! What? that sounds a lot more like stories/design documents/etc... just shared by a PR.

Comment: There's some knowledge and understanding in a developers head. It has value. Your design docs and stories probably won't reflect reality... and are equally unlikely to be read by a future developer. Like... there is a place for learning and there is a place to well indexed knowledge for future reference at a sufficiently general level. I'm not sure if conflating the two is a good move. Your outlook all seems a bit project managery...

Comment: @AttRigh We seem to have left the original question behind. Your point is that PR's are tied directly to a change, and that this somehow makes them ideal for communicating about that change. This might be straw-manning the argument, but when you `git fetch all`. Do you get the conversation thread related to the merge commit of a PR? Its a process to access that history, and has probably aged as well as the stories. Similarly changes rarely happens in a single commit, or a well curated linear set of commits. To appreciate the change usually requires a bit of creative forensics.

Comment: @AttRigh To steel man your argument, I'd say this team has the discipline to rebase, squash, and even split commits till they form a coherent story of change. Along with meaningful commit messages that describe intention and point out what other options were considered and ignored. At this point I'd ask if it wouldn't be easier to add an ADR describing all that information. Stepping back I'd also point out that a lot of our work as software developers isn't to write code, but to consider it, weigh alternatives, identify issues, etc That is actual work that is rarely captured by source control.

Comment: I guess my point is that act of reading code, being tasked with commenting on it, this requiring you understand it, and the person who wrote it answering the questions you have about it creates understanding. Kinda like how doing maths exercises or puzzles helps you learn about maths.  Making this metaphor do some work, the criticisms seem to be "doing and talking about a maths problem isn't a good way of learning maths because it's not a paper or textbook which is a consistent way of laying out maths". Both marked problems and textbooks are useful...